# How could i manage rules to delete specific fields

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

We have an object
**trips/{uid}** with field **users** as a map {uid: info} where could be many users. How could we manage security rules with allowing only remove the same uid as `request.auth.uid`

How have we tried to do that:

```
match /trips/{trip} {
  allow update: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                   request.resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == null;
}
```

But removing field from an object with updates wouldn't work like that.

```
Map<String, Object> removeUser = new HashMap<>();
removeUser.put("users." + user.getUid(), FieldValue.delete())
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection).document(document).update(removeUser)
```

Previous code does something different.

ADDED:

Surprisingly two next rules worked well, but don't fit our requirements:

```
match /trips/{trip} {
  allow update: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                   request.resource.data.users[(request.auth.uid)] !=  null &&
                   request.resource.data.users.size() + 1 == resource.data.users.size();
}
```

Comment: Can you try `allow write` for that?

Comment: We've tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I got it, we deleted the key and trying to check the value which doesn't exists, so it can't be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to check if value isn't **null** but we are deleting the key, so we have to check

```
!(request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.users)
```